# Need Assistance Resolving Windows Batch For /R Infinite Loop with 7-zip

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, 7-zip

I have part of this script that I use to individually encrypt/zip files recursively in a folder structure.

It works, except it seems one particular folder it will go back and start zipping the already zipped files. I can't quite figure out what could be causing it.

Filenames in the folder are all consistent too (they're images). Like "`2017-08-16 18.16.51.jpg`". Once each file is zipped it names the file `file1.7z` `file2.7z` `file3.7z` until it goes through all the files in all the subfolders.

Here is the code:

```
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
...
...
<MORE SCRIPT HERE>
...
...

set count=0
for /r "%sourcedir%" %%a in (*) do (
CLS
set /A count+=1
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set fnz=file!count!.7z

ECHO ***
ECHO *** ENCRYPTING "%%a" as "!fnz!"
ECHO ***
ECHO *** FILE NUMBER !count! OUT OF !files! 
ECHO ***
ECHO %%a !fnz! >> "!batchdir!7ZIP_FILEREF_!folderzip!.txt"

!batchdir!7z.exe a -mx9 -sdel -p"!password!" -mhe=on "%%~dpa!fnz!" "%%a" >nul

ENDLOCAL
)

...
...
<MORE SCRIPT HERE>
...
...
ENDLOCAL
```

Variables `batchdir` and `folderzip` are set earlier on in the script.

Here is some example output from the log when it flips from the last file, to start zipping already zipped file `file100.7z`. File/folder on left is the file being zipped. The file `file###.7z` on right is the zipped file name:

```
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-13 13.24.18.jpg file961.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-13 13.25.02.mp4 file962.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-14 18.03.02.mp4 file963.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-15 12.33.20.jpg file964.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-16 18.16.51.jpg file965.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-16 18.16.53.jpg file966.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-16 18.18.26.jpg file967.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-16 18.18.27.jpg file968.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-16 18.18.29.jpg file969.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-17 13.10.56.jpg file970.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\2017-08-18 06.59.19.jpg file971.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\BMPhoneWallpaper.png file972.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file100.7z file973.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file101.7z file974.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file102.7z file975.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file103.7z file976.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file104.7z file977.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file105.7z file978.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file106.7z file979.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file107.7z file980.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file108.7z file981.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file109.7z file982.7z 
E:\Temp\MDISC\Personal Test C17\Pictures\Camera 2017\file110.7z file983.7z
```

Like I said, so far it's only this ONE subfolder `Camera 2017`. I have other folders like `Camera 2014` `Camera 2015` `Camera 2016` etc like that that zip no problem at all.

Comment: Try restricting your search to only images.

Comment: But I need it to encrypt EVERY file. In EVERY folder. Not just images. I have more than just images. I have other folders with documents and every other kind of file. That's just the strange thing is that it chokes on this particular folder. It's almost like it looks at `file100.7z` as a file that existed before in that folder, when in fact, 7z generated that file during the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for /r loop pharses the files in alphabetical order and it continues pharsing while it is runnig and since you are creating files

```
Areon.jpg  ->file22.7z

Banana.jpg ->file23.7z

Canon.jpg  ->file24.7z

Dallas.jpg ->file25.7z

Elephant   ->file26.7z

file01.7z  ->file27.7z
```

When it reaches "f" it starts including the files that you created with 7zip in the list.

I guess if the source destination files would have the same you wouldn't have that problem:

```
Areon.jpg  ->Areaon.7z
Banana.jpg ->Banana.7z
Canon.jpg  ->Canon.7z
```

Anyway for /r is not the best option if you are working on operations that create files.

Better use a For /f in combination with a dir command:

```
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /s /a "%sourcedir%\*"') do (
```

insted of:

```
for /r "%sourcedir%" %%a in (*) do (
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a shot. But why does it only do it sometimes? I just tried with several different data sets and sometimes it goes through without a problem and other times it does not. It seems it may be a limit on number of files in a folder. Maybe it keeps so many in memory and after that it has to re-reference the list? I dunno. Thanks, I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: If the files created are set before the letter for /r is currently pharsing then there is no problem. For example for /r is pharsing d... and you create files that start with a, b, c then there is no problem because for /r already went through this letters but if you create files that are still going to be pharsed by for /r like e,f,g,h...then there might be a problem. For /f takes 1 shot on the result of the dir command and doesn't repharse anything while it is running it just goes througt the files that the dir command gave him.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work like a charm! I had to remove the /a switch for it to work properly. Thanks again. You saved me losing more hair! :)

Comment: No problemo. The /a switch also includes hidden and system files but if you don't wnat them you can remove it.

Comment: Yeah, regular attributes are fine. Hidden, read-only, or system files aren't necessary for what's needed to be encrypted. Thanks so much.